# Algorithm finding path in an undirected tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree

Suppose I am given a undirected tree and I need to find a path(the only path) between two nodes.

What is the best algorithm to do it.I probably could use a Dijkstra's algorithm but there a probably something better for trees.

C++ example would be helpful but not necessary

Thank you

Comment: You mean finding **THE** path. Unless you allows for a path traversing the same node multiple times then there is just one path from a node to another in a tree (this is one of the possible definitions of tree, actually)

Comment: I posted an answer assuming you're interested also in paths that are partially "upward" even if there are no links to the parent node of a node in your representation. This is not indeed clear in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have

```
struct Node
{
    std::vector<Node *> children;
};
```

then what could be done is traversing the whole tree starting at root keeping the whole chain during the traversal. If you find e.g. node1 then you save the current chain, if you find node2 then you check for the intersection... in code (**UNTESTED**):

```
bool findPath(std::vector<Node *>& current_path, // back() is node being visited
              Node *n1, Node *n2,                // interesting nodes
              std::vector<Node *>& match,        // if not empty back() is n1/n2
              std::vector<Node *>& result)       // where to store the result
{
    if (current_path.back() == n1 || current_path.back() == n2)
    {
        // This is an interesting node...
        if (match.size())
        {
            // Now is easy: current_path/match are paths from root to n1/n2
            ...
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // This is the first interesting node found
            match = current_path;
        }
    }
    for (std::vector<Node *>::iterator i=current_path.back().children.begin(),
                                       e=current_path.back().children.end();
         i != e; ++i)
    {
        current_path.push_back(*i);
        if (findPath(current_path, n1, n2, match, result))
          return true;
        current_path.pop_back(); // *i
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming each node has a pointer to its parent, then simply back-track up the tree towards the root from each start node.  Eventually, the two paths must intersect.  Testing for intersection could be as simple as maintaining a `std::map` of node addresses.

**UPDATE**

As you've updated your question to specify *undirected* trees, then the above isn't valid.  A simple approach is simply to perform a depth-first traversal starting at Node #1, eventually you'll hit Node #2.  This is *O(n)* in the size of the tree.  I'm not sure there's going to be a faster approach than that, assuming a completely general tree.

Comment: I am talking about undirected tree

Comment: @Yakov: Well, yes, that clearly makes a difference!  Glad to see you've updated your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Breadth-first search and depth-first search are more effective then Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Isn't Dijksta's algo identical to Breadth-first search if all edge weights are one (or more general identical)?

Comment: It's not. If you use Dijkstra, you have to select the closest unvisited intersection (it's slow). So, the complexity is O(E + V logV), E - edges, V - vertices, if you use Fibonacci heap to extract minimum. If you use Breadth-first search, the complexity is O(E+V) = O(V) (it's a tree, so E = V - 1).